# Is there a jQuery plugin for check lists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create some step-by-step online instructions and I want users to check off step s that they complete as they go along.

Ideally, there would be a checkbox next to each step.  When they click it, it will cross-out that step and show it as being completed.

Is there any plugins that do something like this?

Comment: Do you need a plug-in? You may simply use one line javascript on checkbox live event to apply a class (with strikethrough style) to next _div_ or _p_ or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a plugin. Let's say you have this markup:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Step 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Step 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Step 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox">Step 4</li>
</ul>
```

This will strike out the items when checked and remove it when unchecked:

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var element = $(this).parent();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       element.wrap('<del>');
    } else {
       element.unwrap('<del>');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/awMhq/

Just make sure you have the correct CSS set up for `<del>` so it appears with a line through it, something like `del {text-decoration: line-through; color:#f00}`

You'll have to decide what makes sense for you in order to save the progress from one page/step to the next.

Comment: That's pretty cool!  But I forgot to mention something.  I will need the checklist to remember the settings of the user so they can use the checklist over a period of days.  Would that be set with a cookie?  Is this really complex?

Comment: That's the part that depends entirely on your application, and that a plugin would not be able to guess for you. I would assume you use cookies or a database. Without a clear spec, it's hard to say much more. There are lots of resources available for learning about either of those options - let me see if I can find some... Is this for anonymous users or registered ones? How long do you need to store the data, what *is* the data, etc.?

Comment: This would be for anonymous users and I'd like to store the settings for at least one week.  The data is just text strings.  Basic step by step instructions that they can check off as they do them.